# How to repeat execution of a java file at a specific interval in the background?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-service

I am working on an Android app for my personal use which will execute a java code at specific intervals of time in the background when the app is installed in my device.

In Android Studio how to do it.

The following is the code which I want to run.

```
public class myJava {

  public static void main(String[] args){
   System.out.println("I want to be repeated");
   //other codes
  }
}
```

I used `thread` and `Timer` but its not working. Maybe I am doing something wrong. Can anyone please guide me.

The API level is 28.

Comment: What have you tried? What problem are you encountering?

Comment: @JavierMendonça Actually I'm completely noob  at making Android apps. I just know coding in java. I'm not experiencing any error but the problem is whatever I'm doing to make it run it's not working. When I open the app in my phone then the code is not executed of myJava.java file. Can you please help me. Thank you.

Comment: @JavierMendonça In short, I want to run and execute a java code which is inside a java file. I want the code to run in background at specific intervals when the app is installed in my device.

Comment: Look at the Android `WorkManager`

Comment: @JavierMendonça Ok. I implemented the WorkManager step by step from a YouTube video. But when I click the Button which will start the Work, my app closes. Also there is no App not responding warning. It just closes.